# Erro ao trocar a porta mysql no xampp

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

Por precisar usar o MySQL Workbench pra faculdade, deixei a porta 3306 pro server do Workbench e troquei a do XAMPP por 3307 como o rapaz Suman Kotagiri disse nesse forum https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-change-the-port-of-a-MySQL-server-in-XAMPP

Quando dei start no módulo MySQL no XAMPP pensei que poderia dar algum erro, mas não, ele ficou verde e disse que seu status estava como 'funcionando'(running). Só que quando clicko em admin, essa janela aparece no phpmyadmin:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não existem muitas dúvidas exatamente sobre isso então fica meio vago sobre o que pode estar acontecendo. Existe a possibilidade de estar tendo algum conflito do Workbench com o XAMPP mesmo assim? Eu desliguei o servidor pelo MySQL Notifier por pensar que haveria problema em ter dois servidores ligados ao mesmo tempo mas não me que ajudou 100% pra dar certo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tens de [mudar a configuração de ligação do PHPMyAdmin](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/pt_BR/latest/config.html).

Para isso, vais a pasta onde está o PHPMyAdmin e encontras o ficheiro `config.inc.php`, ai vais ter uma configuração tipo `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port']` que terás de mudar para apontar para a nova porta, `3307`.

Ele devia conseguir ligar ao outro serviço que tens a correr na `3306`, mas isto seria se os dados de acesso fossem os mesmos, que pode não ser o caso aqui.

Também podes nesse ficheiro de configuração ter mais de 1 servidor configurado (tal como no Workbench), portanto até podes criar mais configurações de ligação para poderes usar a mesma ferramenta e gerir ambos os serviços de base de dados.

Só por curiosidade, alguma razão especifica para ter 2 serviços? Não és obrigado para usar o Workbench.

Comment: Dentro do config.inc.php não tem '$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port']', tem 'user', 'password', 'host', 'extension' e outros, menos port :/ E o workbench é pro projeto da faculdade enquanto que o Xampp é pra estudo pessoal, seria um pra Java e outro pra PHP. Até sei como usar o Xampp no NetBeans mas é uma exigência o Workbench mesmo

Comment: Seguindo o formato que uma das outras usa (por exemplo, duplica o `host`), cria uma entrada para o `port` e coloca o valor a `3307`. O Workbench faz o mesmo que o PHPMyAdmin, podias ter só 1 serviço de MySQL e ter Workbench e PHPMyAdmin a ligarem-se ao mesmo, mas depois ter bases de dados diferentes (dentro desse serviço) para cada projecto em que vais trabalhar (estudo pessoal ou da faculdade).

Comment: Mesmo depois de apertar o Start no MySQL e aparecer "Problem detected! Port 3306 in use by "Unable to open process"! MySQL WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!", ele funciona! Quero dizer, agora entra no phpmyadmin, amanhã farei os testes pra ver se consigo pegar os dados. Obrigado pela ajuda @Leite. Sobre ter só 1 serviço de MySQL, você diz ter ou Xampp ou o Workbench instalado?

Answer (score -1):

Fui na pasta phpyadmin e achei o ficheiro config.inc.php

dupliquei a linha $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';

e alterei o host para port e adicionei a

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '3307';